# How to find character of standard representation of $S_n$?

Tags: representation-theory

If we consider the three-dimensional subspace of all vectors of the form $x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3 + x_4e_4$ where $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 0$ then $e_1 - e_2, e_2 - e_3$, and $e_3 - e_4$ will form a basis for this vector space. Similarly we can take an $(n-1)$ dimensional vector space for $S_n$.
Can you please explain how to find and prove the formula for the character of standard representation for $S_n$.

Comment: Subtract the trivial character from the regular character.

Answer (score 0):

Here I try to provide a bit more detail on why Lord Shark the Unknown's answer is correct (and also attempt to take this out of the unanswered questions list).

Let $\rho_n : S_n \to V$ be the permutation (regular) representation of $S_n$ over a field $\mathsf{k}$ of characteristic zero, by which I mean that $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathsf{k}$ with a basis $\mathcal{B} = \left\{ e_{\sigma} \mid \sigma \in S_n \right\}$ consisting of elements indexed by the elements $\sigma$ of $S_n$ (in any order, doesn't really matter), and $\rho_n$ acts by

$$
\rho_n(\tau)(e_{\sigma}) = e_{\tau\sigma}.
$$

Now the subspace $W$ of $V$ defined by

$$
W = \left\{ \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} a_{\sigma}e_\sigma \mid \left\{ a_\sigma  \right\}_{\sigma \in S_n}  \subseteq \mathsf{k} : \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} a_{\sigma} = 0   \right\},
$$

is a subrepresentation of $V$. Indeed it is standard representation. A neat way to see that $W$ is indeed a representation of $S_n$ comes from considering the map:

$$
T : V \to \mathsf{k} \ : \ \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} a_{\sigma}e_\sigma \mapsto \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} a_{\sigma}.
$$

Then $T$ is clearly a linear map of vector spaces, but it is also a map of representations, where we are considering $\mathsf{k}$ to be the trivial representation of $S_n$. Indeed

$$
T(\tau \cdot e_{\sigma}) = T(e_{\sigma \tau}) = 1 = \tau \cdot 1  = \tau \cdot T(e_{\sigma}),
$$
for all $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$. It follows that the kernel of $T$ is a subrepresentation of $V$, but this kernel is precisely $W$. Moreover, since $T$ is clearly surjective, by the rank nullity formula it follows that the dimension of $W$ is $\operatorname{dim}V - 1 = n-1$.

Now since $\mathsf{k}$ has characteristic zero, and $S_n$ is a finite group, [Mashke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem) states that any finite dimensional representation, $V$ say, of $S_n$ over $\mathsf{k}$ is completely reducible. By which I mean that if $U$ is any subrepresentation of $V$, there exists some other subrepresentation $U'$ of $V$ satisfying $V = U \oplus U'$.

Now returning to the permutation representation of $S_n$, we now know that there must exist some subrepresentation $W'$ of $V$ satisfying $V = W \oplus W'$. Moreover, any such $W'$ must be one-dimensional since $\operatorname{dim}W = \operatorname{dim}V - 1$. Hence any such $W'$ must be a one-dimensional subrepresentation of $V$ disjoint from $W$ and any such subrepresentation is a valid choice for $W'$. Which is to say that we can choose $W'$ to be generated by any $v \in V$ that is not in $W$ and also $\rho_n(\tau)(v) \in \mathsf{k} \cdot v$ for all $\tau \in S_n$. For instance $v = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} e_{\sigma}$ works. Now notice that $\rho_n(\tau)(v) = v$ for all $\tau \in S_n$, and so $W'$ is in fact the trivial representation.

We have thus shown that the permutation representation $\rho_n$ is the direct sum of the standard representation $\rho_{n,\operatorname{st}}$ and the trivial representation $\rho_{n,0}$. Hence, on the level of characters we have $\chi_n = \chi_{n, \operatorname{st}} + \chi_{n,0}$, and so finally indeed

$$
\chi_{n, \operatorname{st}} = \chi_n - \chi_{n,0}.
$$

Comment: Great answer +1